# Uncaught reference Error first chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So i have been making my first chrome extension. What it is supposed to do is remove a certain `<tr>` when none of the `<td>`'s in the row contains the word on the button.  The error I'm getting is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>    at chrome-extension://.../scripts/popup.js:2
>   (anonymous) @ chrome-extension://.../scripts/popup.js:2

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and if this is the only fault I am making here. Could anyone explain what i am doing wrong and maybe help me on my way a bit code-wise.

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Popup with search</title>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
<link rel="manifest.json" href="manifest.json">
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Remove all rows which don't contain:</h3>
<div class="container">
    <div class="Type">
        <h3>Types:</h3>
        <button id="PRICAT">PRICAT</button>
    </div>
    <div class="Format">
        <h3>Formats:</h3>
        <button id="RetailConnect">RetailConnect</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

manifest.json:

```
 {
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "CE QuickSearch ",
"version": "0.1",

"browser_action": {
"default_popup": "popup.html",
"default_title": "Popup with search"
},
"description": "Made by me",
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [ "https://url_i_use_it_on/*" ],
  "all_frames":  true,
  "js": [ "scripts/content.js", "scripts/popup.js"]
}
],

"permissions": [
"https://url_i_use_it_on/Message"
],
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js; object-src 
'self'"
}
```

Popup.js:

```
 $("#PRICAT").click(function PRICAT() {
 var searchString = $(this).text();
 $("#tbody tr td:contains('" + searchString + "')").closest('tr').remove();
 });

 $("#RetailConnect").click(function RetailConnect() {
 var searchString = $(this).text();
 $("#tbody tr td:contains('" + searchString + "')").closest('tr').remove();
 });
```

content.js:

```
 console.log("CE QuickSearch is activated..");
```

Comment: In your `"content_scripts"` section, you include `popup.js` but not jQuery. Therefore, when `popup.js` runs, `$` is an undefined variable. You have to download jQuery and include it in your `"content_scripts":"js"` section, before `popup.js`.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko thank you! I added the jQuery to my js library and placed it in my content_scripts. So the error is gone but the buttons on my extension still don't work. Would you have any clue why that is?

Comment: It's a terrible idea to load scripts remotely. Remove your CSP and load jquery.js locally.